# Telerik remote virtualization (Kendo Grid)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a question about how the Telerik grid stores data internally after fetching it as part of infinite scroll operations. I am using the remote virtualization mode and fetch new records through Ajax calls.

I am able to access the data set that is currently bound to the grid through:

```
$("#Grid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.view()
```

As expected the grid makes an Ajax request to request new pages, but it seems to store data for previous pages in an object somewhere. Is there a way to acccess that object through the cient side API? Meaning can I view all the data for all the pages that were requested by the grid (not just the current page)?

I have also noticed that the grid will often make the same Ajax request twice during scrolling (for the same page number). Is there a way to prevent this since the duplicate request seems to return the same data as the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the data is stored in chunks of data called "ranges" within the internal **_ranges** array.

You can cycle through all the loaded data like this:

```
var chunks = $('#gridName').data().kendoGrid.dataSource._ranges
for(var i=0;i<chunks.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<chunks[i].data.length;j++){
        console.log(chunks[i].data[j])
    }
}
```

Regarding the multiple same requests - I think this is addressed and if it is not already fixed in the **latest internal build** it should be in the nearest releases.